# Converting human readable date to a unix timestamp

Tags: arduino-uno, timers, gps, time, convert

Can anyone provide a sample code that would convert a human readable date like `2019-10-27 22:10:35` to a unix timestamp like `1572214235`?

I found many topics about it, but they eider refer to out of date libraries, or they seem to address more complex time functions, I find it hard to extract this functionality from them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a fixed format you can use `strtok()` to slice the string into individual segments, then convert those segments to integers. They can then be used with `TimeLib.h` with the `setTime()` function.  You can then query TimeLib for the unix timestamp with `now()`.

**Edit:** using [PaulStoffregen's TimeLib](https://github.com/PaulStoffregen/Time), this code sets current time and returns current unix timestamp.

```
#include <TimeLib.h>

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // hour, min, sec, day, month, year
  setTime(22, 30, 11, 29, 3, 2019);

  // 1553898611
  Serial.println(now());
}
void loop() {}
```

**Edit 2:** And to convert **any** given date to a unix timestamp (without setting current time):

```
#include "TimeLib.h"

tmElements_t my_time;  // time elements structure
time_t unix_timestamp; // a timestamp

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // convert a date and time into unix time, offset 1970
  my_time.Second = 0;
  my_time.Hour = 23;
  my_time.Minute = 0;
  my_time.Day = 25;
  my_time.Month = 3 - 1;      // months start from 0, so deduct 1
  my_time.Year = 2017 - 1970; // years since 1970, so deduct 1970

  unix_timestamp =  makeTime(my_time);
  Serial.println(unix_timestamp);
}

void loop() {}
```

Comment: I already have them into separate values like year, month, etc, I just have no clue on how the code should look when using the time library. I am new to Arduino.

Comment: Pass the values to setTime() - I forget the order, but I think it's `setTime(hours, minutes, seconds, year, month, day)` - though check the documentation or source to be sure.  Then you get the time since the unix epoch with `now()`.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to do that and added a full sample code in your answer, I still need a way to convert any given date (not just current time).

Comment: I hope you don't mind, I altered a code once more so I am able to select your answer as the correct one :D

Answer (score 2):

After parsing the time into numbers, you can use the standard C time library `time.h`. More specifically, use the `mktime` [function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/mktime) to convert a `struct tm` into a `time_t`, and use `difftime` to get the seconds since the start of the Unix expoch:

```
#include <time.h>

void loop() {
    struct tm ltm = {0};
    ltm.tm_year = 2019 - 1900;
    ltm.tm_mon  = 11 - 1;
    ltm.tm_mday = 5;

    int32_t epoch_seconds = difftime(mktime(&ltm), (time_t)0);
    Serial.print("Remember, remember, ");
    Serial.print(epoch_seconds);
}
```

Note that in `struct tm`, the year starts at 1900 and the month starts at 0.

EDIT: In avr-libc, `difftime` returns an `int32_t`, not a `double`.

Comment: So I replace 2019 with my year and I leave/append the ` -1900` part, same for month, then where do I specify the hour, minute and second ?

Comment: @adrianTNT Yes, you can use `tm_hour`, `tm_min` and `tm_sec` to specify hours, minutes and seconds, respectively. The available fields of `struct tm` are linked in the reference. Cf. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/tm

Comment: I tried the code, seems close but I get a timestamp like `626227200.00` which (without `.00`) is around 1989, I am lost.

Comment: `Serial.print` might have some trouble printing double-precision floats. Does it work when you change it to `Serial.print((float)epoch_seconds, 0);`? This should also cut off the '.00' decimal places at the end.

Comment: Do I have to set current time first ? If I just set year to `0` and no month or day, it prints a timestamp since `2006-02-07` (1139293696). In another answer I was able to set current time and print current timestamp, but converting any date with `mktime` would be nice.

Comment: The order of setting variables should not matter. It's odd that it prints unrelated times. I did experience something similar before I added the `= {0}` part. It's either an initialization error (you could check by printing a non-set member of `ltm`, e.g. `Serial.print(ltm.yday)` and see if this is always 0); or it might be a problem with `Serial.print` itself (did you convert it to `float`? Or try using `char buf[20]; sprintf(buf, "%.10g", epoch_seconds); Serial.print(buf)` instead).

Comment: That timestamp seems to be a default or an offset, I found web results when searching for `arduino 1139293696`. I think different time components inside the library might use different defaults/offsets. I will do some more tests.

Comment: Note that: 1. `mktime()` interprets the time as being in the local time zone, which on AVR is UTC until you change it with `set_zone()`/`set_dst()`. 2. avr-libc uses the epoch 2000-01-01. If you want a Unix timestamp, you should use `mktime(&ltm) + UNIX_OFFSET`.

Comment: "2038". When using int32, it means only 31 valid bits for real numbers, the final bit (MSb) is the negative sign. So we can only get a number of 2'147'483'647, and that arrives at the year 2038. If someone needs to increase this, perhaps the simplest thing would be to use a base year to subtract, and avoid overflow. Maybe that's why the year 2000 is used as a base, and maybe it's interesting to use 2020. Try this yourself: https://timestampgenerator.com/date-from-timestamp/2147483647/+00:00